# Trying to install a YANG plugin in Eclpse -JavaEditorMessages.SemantincHighlighting has encountered a prpblem

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ietf-netmod-yang

I am trying to install a YANG plugin in Eclipse 
https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-boron/getting-started-guide/project-specific-guides/yangide.html
I am getting this error and I have no idea how to fix this
Does anybody know what is wrong here ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a non issue
You can't create YANG files just anywhere (as I tried)
On the page I linked there is an explaination on how to start a project
Follow that and you will be fine , create any new yang file withing the project folders